# How to Download Zip file which is coming from the webservice callout

Tags: apex, integration, json

Hello Developer: I have a requirement where an end user has to click into one lighting button, after click one API call will happen and I will receive response in Binary string which is nothing but Zip file and will contains multiple documents.
My requirement is when user click into the button the Zip file should be downloaded.
I am successfully able to make a callout and receiving the response, now only want to deserialize this stream and make it for downloadable in Zip.
Can anyone suggest how this achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve my problem as below:

1. Received the response from API and return that to JS contoller from Apex method as:

   HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

   return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(response.getBodyAsBlob());
2. And in the JS Controller process this encoded Bolb file as:

   ```
       action.setCallback(this,function(response) { 

        var state = response.getState();
        if(state == "SUCCESS") {
            // Start file download.
            var element = document.createElement('a');
            element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;base64,' + response.getReturnValue());
            element.setAttribute('download', selectedPO.Name+'.zip');

            element.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(element);

            element.click();

            document.body.removeChild(element);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
   ```